# Change only a specific owner when extracting tar archive

Tags: tar, permissions

I have a tar archive containing two owners, 1000 and 0 :

```
$ tar tfvz archive.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 1000/1000         main/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               main/root_dir/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               main/root_dir/home/
-rw-r--r-- 1000/1000         main/root_dir/home/file
```

Is there a simple way to change ownership only on directories/files with owner 1000 ? Those with owner 0 must stay unchanged.

I didn't find any options in tar or find that select a specific owner, for example `tar --no-same-owner` change all owners, not only owner 1000 (I extract archive with `sudo tar xfz archive.tgz` to allow creation of root (0) directories/files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use find's uid switch to do this after you have extracted the files

```
find /path/to/files -uid 1000 -exec chown newuid:newgid {} +
```